# Uploaded images and browser detection

Tags: ee3, redirection, mobile

I have main installation of EE3 (test.example.com) and subdomain (m-test.example.com) for mobile version. Also I use detectmobilebrowser.com for detecting the device. Everything work well despite images. Mobile version will have the same content, images etc. as main version.

So this URL works: `test.example.com/images/upload/folder/image.jpg` but this one unfortunately not: `m-test.example.com/images/upload/folder/image.jpg`. Templates are loading properly but without images.

I found out the problem has been created by detectmobilebrowser.com because without this the images work properly on subdomain (`m-test.example.com`). So the problem is starting when someone go to `test.example.com` by mobile and will be redirected to `m-test.example.com`. Then images not working. When you go to `m-test.example.com` by desktop, everything will be fine.

What is the reason of that and how to deal with it?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Where in your load order do you redirect? PHP via templates or perhaps right in `index.php` or the JS version on the front-end? Also, have you tried using your browsers mobile emulator, and then investigation your non-loading image elements?

Comment: I detected the device by server (nginx). I think the problem was when server detect the mobile version, change the address and then images didn't load. Anyway thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I change the way of making mobile version of site. I'm going to stay at the same URL and use Mobile Detect script (http://mobiledetect.net/) in my templates. So I do not have to create a new subdomain and detect device by server. To be honest, this is something I was looking for.